# Scrollviewer visibility after debugging

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Application. I added a scrollviewer to a window. However I can see the scrollviewer during the design. When I debug the project then the scrollviewer does not seem...

There is the code

```
                  </local:WorkControl.DataContext>
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Grid Name="mainGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top">

    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" TileMode="FlipXY" Viewport="0,0,1479,437" ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
    </Grid.Background>

        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1,1,1,1" Name="dockPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
        <Grid Name="grid1" Width="Auto" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" OpacityMask="Black" ShowGridLines="False" OverridesDefaultStyle="False">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="310" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="123" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" Name="borAdrTopR" VerticalAlignment="Top" CornerRadius="5"
        AllowDrop="False">
                <Canvas Width="834" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="panelTop" ContextMenuOpening="panelTop_ContextMenuOpening">
                    <TextBlock Name="txAdrID" Canvas.Left="11" Canvas.Top="11" Height="20" Text="AdrID:" Width="44" Foreground="Silver" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding [AdrID]}" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,11,602,0" Name="tbAdrID" Width="86" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Foreground="Silver" Canvas.Left="54" Canvas.Top="-1" Padding="1" BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" />
                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="488" Canvas.Top="11" Height="20" Text="Adresspool:" Width="70" TextAlignment="Right" />
                    <CheckBox Canvas.Left="570" Canvas.Top="11" Content="MSS" Height="16" Name="chkMSSPool" Checked="chkPool_Checked" Unchecked="chkPool_Checked" />
                    <CheckBox Canvas.Left="620" Canvas.Top="11" Content="GMM" Height="16" Name="chkGMMPool" Checked="chkPool_Checked" Unchecked="chkPool_Checked" />
                    <CheckBox Canvas.Left="675" Canvas.Top="11" Content="MZ" Height="16" Name="chkMZPool" Checked="chkPool_Checked" Unchecked="chkPool_Checked" IsEnabled="False" />
                    <CheckBox Canvas.Left="728" Canvas.Top="11" Content="Sage" Height="16" Name="chkSagePool" Checked="chkPool_Checked" Unchecked="chkPool_Checked" />
                    <CheckBox Canvas.Left="780" Canvas.Top="11" Content="Web" Height="16" Name="chkMyMalikPool" IsEnabled="False" Checked="chkPool_Checked" Unchecked="chkPool_Checked" />
                    <TextBox Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Canvas.Left="367" Canvas.Top="9" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" Height="21" IsReadOnly="True" Name="tbSecInfo"
            Padding="1" Text="" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Width="101" />
                    <Image Canvas.Left="268" Canvas.Top="11" Height="16" Name="imgCRMstatus" Stretch="None" Width="96" MouseLeftButtonUp="imgCRMstatus_MouseClick"
            MouseRightButtonUp="imgCRMstatus_MouseClick" />
                    <Label Canvas.Left="257" Canvas.Top="17" Height="11" Name="lbCRMStatus" Width="9" IsEnabled="False" />
                    <Image Canvas.Left="466" Canvas.Top="7" Height="24" Name="imgSec" Stretch="None" Width="24" MouseRightButtonUp="imgSec_MouseClick" MouseLeftButtonUp="imgSec_MouseClick"
            Visibility="Hidden" />
                </Canvas>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="borAddress" VerticalAlignment="Top" CornerRadius="5" Background="White"
        AllowDrop="False">
                <FlowDocumentScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="fdocview" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="#FFFFFFF9"
          Margin="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="0" MinHeight="118">
                    <FlowDocument TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="12" PagePadding="5">
                        <FlowDocument.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkBlue" />
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Trebuchet MS" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                            </Style>
                        </FlowDocument.Resources>
                        <Paragraph>ViewControl...mmm</Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3" Name="borAdrInfoLeft" CornerRadius="6" AllowDrop="False">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="73" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <local:ComboBoxCW Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="cbAdrTypeID" CWListName="Adresstypen" Background="#FFC8D2E8"
            SelectedID="{Binding Path=[AdrTypeID]}" SelectionChanged="cwAdrType_SelectionChanged" Margin="0,0,0,3" />
                    <local:ComboBoxCW Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="cbGruppenID" SelectedID="{Binding [GruppenID]}" CWListName="Gruppen" Background="#FFC8D2E8"
            CWListArt="withall" CWListFilter="M" Margin="0,0,0,3" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Name="txtBedeutung" Text="$$" Width="22" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="tbKundenNr" Canvas.Left="83" Text="{Binding [KundenNr]}" BorderBrush="#96000000" MaxLength="30" Margin="0,0,0,3" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Name="tbCRA" Text="{Binding [CRA]}" BorderBrush="#96000000" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0,0,0,3" />
                    <local:ComboBoxCW Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="cwSprachID" SelectedID="{Binding [SprachID],Mode=TwoWay}" CWListName="Sprachen" CWListArt="withempty"
            Margin="0,0,0,3" />
                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Name="cbBedeutung" Text="{Binding Path=[Bedeutung]}">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content=" " />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="A" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="B" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="C" />
                    </ComboBox>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Adressart" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Gruppe" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Kundennr." />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="CRA" TextAlignment="Right" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="Sprache" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Text="Bed." TextAlignment="Right" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3" Name="borAdrInfoRight" CornerRadius="6" AllowDrop="False">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="73" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <local:ComboBoxCW Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="cbAdrStatusID" SelectedID="{Binding [AdrStatusID]}" CWListName="Adressstati" Margin="0,0,0,3"
            Background="#FFC8D2E8" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="tbMZunitID"
            Text="{Binding [MZunitID],Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource codetextfromid}, ConverterParameter=MZunits}" Margin="0,0,0,3" BorderBrush="#96000000"
            IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <local:ComboBoxCW Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="cbBetreuerID" Text="" Background="#FFC8D2E8" CWListName="Mitarbeiter" Margin="0,0,0,3"
            SelectedID="{Binding Path=[BetreuerID]}" CWListArt="withall" />
                    <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="listBetreuers" BorderBrush="#96000000" SelectionChanged="listBetreuers_SelectionChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,3" />
                    <Popup Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" OpacityMask="#00000000" Name="popAdd" StaysOpen="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=listBetreuers}"
            Placement="Bottom" HorizontalOffset="-40" VerticalOffset="-20">
                        <ListBox Height="160" Width="270" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listAdd" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="listAdd_SelectionChanged" />
                    </Popup>
                    <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Content="-" Height="22" Width="22" Name="btnBetreuerDel" Click="btnBetreuerDel_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Content="+" Height="22" Width="22" Name="btnBetreuerAdd" Click="btnBetreuerAdd_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Content="H" Height="22" Width="22" Name="btnBetreuerHaupt" Click="btnBetreuerHaupt_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Status" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Unit" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Name="lbHauptbetrP" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Hauptbetr." />
                    <TextBlock Name="lbHauptbetrF" Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Account-Mgr." />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="weitere Betreuer" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <!-- ====TAB Firma start -->
            <TabControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="tabReg" Margin="0" SelectionChanged="tabReg_SelectionChanged" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="2,2">
                <TabItem Header="Firma" Name="regFirma" local:HelpProvider.HelpParameter="AddressControl;Firma">
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!-- ====Firmen-Felder linke Seite -->
                        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3" Name="borFeed0" CornerRadius="6" AllowDrop="False">
                            <Grid Margin="2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="95" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="38" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Firma" />
                                <Button Name="btnLinkFirma" Height="23" Width="23" ToolTip="Mit Firma verknüpfen..." Click="btnLinkFirma_Click" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                                    <Button.Content>
                                        <Image Source="Images/Verknuepfung_32.png" />
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>
                                <TextBox Name="tbFirma" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,3" Text="{Binding Path=[Firma]}" BorderBrush="#96000000"
                  MouseDoubleClick="tbFirma_MouseDoubleClick" MaxLength="80" AcceptsReturn="True" />
                                <TextBox x:Name="tbFirmazusatz" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,3" Text="{Binding Path=[Firmazusatz]}" BorderBrush="#96000000"
                  MaxLength="50" />
```

There are more codes

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Aghilas's answer

If you have set HorizontalScrollBarVisibility, VerticalScrollBarVisibility properties to 'Auto', try setting them to Visible.

Comment: I made them visible, unfornutely does not seem after the debugging.

Comment: If you are facing issue around scroll bars for FlowDocumentScrollViewer, then you need to set VerticalScrollBarVisibility to 'Visible' on FlowDocumentScrollViewer as well.